# Read a binary file into an array

Tags: file-io, vb6

What's the fastest way (using VB6) to read an entire, large, binary file into an array?

Answer (score 14):

Here's one way, although you are limited to files around 2 GB in size.

```
  Dim fileNum As Integer
  Dim bytes() As Byte

  fileNum = FreeFile
  Open "C:\test.bin" For Binary As fileNum
  ReDim bytes(LOF(fileNum) - 1)
  Get fileNum, , bytes
  Close fileNum
```

Comment: Why loop? Just `Get fileNum, , bytes` and speed it up 100x

Comment: On the `Get fileNum, , data` I get a `Run-time Error 458, Variable uses an Automation Type not supported in Visual Basic`. Any idea what's going on? Am I missing a library reference?

Comment: OK. Got it! Change it into this: `ReDim bytes(1 To lenF) As Byte`. Apparently I was using Variant and it didn't like it at all...

Answer (score 7):

You can compare these two

```
Private Function ReadFile1(sFile As String) As Byte()
    Dim nFile       As Integer

    nFile = FreeFile
    Open sFile For Input Access Read As #nFile
    If LOF(nFile) > 0 Then
        ReadFile1 = InputB(LOF(nFile), nFile)
    End If
    Close #nFile
End Function

Private Function ReadFile2(sFile As String) As Byte()
    Dim nFile       As Integer

    nFile = FreeFile
    Open sFile For Binary Access Read As #nFile
    If LOF(nFile) > 0 Then
        ReDim ReadFile2(0 To LOF(nFile) - 1)
        Get nFile, , ReadFile2
    End If
    Close #nFile
End Function
```

I prefer the second one but it has this nasty side effect. If `sFile` does not exists `For Binary` mode creates an empty file no matter that `Access Read` is used.